# Java DataAware components

Tags: java

Is there any free data aware components for java, like good old Jbuilder components?
For example data aware visual grid component where you can add, modify, commit data to database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NetBeans has pretty good support for this sort of stuff.

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db.html